# Is it a good practice to assign atributes to the tester class that will be used by other tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest

I'm writing unit tests for my python app with pytest.

The module I'm testing has many methods that will be called in sequence and their returns are to be used as arguments to the other ones. In short what I have is something like this:

```
def foo_1():
    #load file and do stuff
    return bar_1

def foo_2(arg1):
    #do stuff with arg1
    return bar_2

def foo_3(arg1, arg2):
    #do stuff with arg1 and arg2
    return bar_3

x = foo_1()
y = foo_2(x)
z = foo_3(x,y)
```

Pretty basic stuff, and this are the tests I'm running:

```
import foo_app

class TestClass:

    def test_foo_1(self):
        self.x = foo_app.foo_1()

        #never mind the assertions
        assert 0 == self.x

    def test_foo_2(self):
        self.y = foo_app.foo_2(self.x)

        #never mind the assertions
        assert 1 == self.y

    def test_foo_3(self):
        self.z = foo_app.foo_3(self.x, self.y)

        #never mind the assertions
        assert 3 == self.z
```

However, I'd like to know if this is a good practice on unit testing, and if not what is the best way to deal with this kind of scenario where I depend on the executions of previous methods to achieve my result?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve desired behavior using yield. Which can be used to maintain sequence of executions.

```
def foo_1():
    #load file and do stuff
    return bar_1

def foo_2(arg1):
    #do stuff with arg1
    return bar_2

def foo_3(arg1, arg2):
    #do stuff with arg1 and arg2
    return bar_3
def run():
    arg1 = foo_1()
    yield
    arg2 = foo_2(arg1)
    yield
    arg3 = foo_3(arg1,arg2)
    yield

for steps in run():
    pass
```

Check out this resource where he explained in detail how it works.
https://youtu.be/7lmCu8wz8ro?t=4635